# Distorted HTML email in outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook

I have an email template which works with other email client but, Outlook shows it as distorted (inner div). Here i have specified width of my inner div 920px but in not take effect in outlook. I have either tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15970660/html-email-in-outlook-table-width-issue-content-is-wider-than-the-specified-ta) but not works

This is my html email template

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div style="width:950;margin:0px auto;">
         <img style="width:100%;" src="cid:header">
         <div style="background-color: #f3f3f3;width: 920px;padding: 15px 15px 20px 15px;margin: 0px;font-family: arial,sans-serif;font-size: 12.8px;box-sizing: border-box;color:#000;white-space:pre-line;" >
             Dear xyz
             <br><br>
             My mail body 
             <!-- Body might contain table  -->
             <br><br>
             support<br>
         </div>
         <a href='https://example.com'><img style="width:100%;" src="cid:footer"></a>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

I have refer [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137540/html-email-in-outlook)  and [emailology](http://www.emailology.org/#2) but no solution found for div.

Please help me.

Comment: The common tip is to build HTML emails from tables rather than relying on divs & CSS

Comment: Outlook supports a maximum width of 800 pixels. You'll never get to 950.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use standard front-end development solutions for emails.  It's unfortunate, but using table-based layouts is still the best way to handle it.  Also, as a general rule of thumb, email widths should fall between 600-800px at the max.